# How to execute cdk commands with contextual parameters when cdk is not installed i.e., using npm run cdk?

Tags: npm, aws-cdk

I have a cdk stack named Temp to which I want to pass contextual parameters.

```
new MyStack(app, `Temp`);
```

When I run the following command in bash, I get the synthesized template successfully:

```
cdk synth Temp -c param1=abc
```

However when I run the following, I am getting an error saying *No stack found matching 'param1=abc'. Use "list" to print manifest*

```
npm run cdk synth Temp -c param1=abc
```

Please advise how to execute cdk synth with contextual parameters when cdk is not installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works by adding -- as follows:

`npm run cdk synth Temp -- -c param1=abc`

Thanks to https://jurosh.com/blog/npm-pass-parameters-into-script

We can use special npm command -- and pass parameters directly into all running scripts. Like this: `npm start -- --server=localhost`

Comment: Can you add an example of reading those parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CfnParameter` to pass an argument to your stack, check `CfnParameter` API [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ssm.CfnParameter.html)

- First create your `CfnParameter`:

  `const parameterName = new CfnParameter(this, "parameterName", {type:"String"});`
- Pass it to your stack:

  `new MyStack(app, 'Temp', { paramPassed: parameterName.valueAsString});`
- Run cdk synth:

  `cdk synth`
- Pass parameter to your stack:

  `cdk deploy Temp --parameters parameterName=stackParamValue`

Check this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/parameters.html) provided by AWS